# multiple cURL and output JSON?

Tags: php, json, curl

I have written a multiple curl and it outputs two different arrays

I'm using curl_multi_getcontent.

```
    for($i = 0; $i < $node_count; $i++)
    {

        $results = curl_multi_getcontent  ( $curl_arr[$i]  );
        $results = json_decode($results,true);

        /*echo "<pre>";
        print_r($results);
        echo "</pre>";*/
    }
```

This outputs two arrays. if I wanted to get data from one of the arrays, how do I call the first array? or the second array?

Is there something like $results[0] or something for the first array

```
foreach($results[0] as $result){
    echo $result['pagination']; 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, as of right now, the $result variables are overwritting each other through the for loop. Try this:

```
for($i = 0; $i < $node_count; $i++)
{
    $results[$i] = curl_multi_getcontent  ( $curl_arr[$i]  );
    $results[$i] = json_decode($results,true);
}

print_r($results);
```

You should now have two elements in your array that you can call via `$results[0]` or `$results[1]` etc...

Comment: This doesn't show the json string, it just goes 
`Array 
{ 
[0]=>
[1]=>
}` and theres no value in those

Comment: what data do you have in the `$curl_arr` array?

Comment: i didn't change anything in regards to your curl object, so it should have the same arrays that you said it was printing out in your original post. If you include more of your code, that will help.

Comment: I got it to work now. You have to add [$i] in the json_decode as well. but for some reason I can't get to output the value. if I use `foreach($results[0] as $result){echo $result['data'];}` know of any reason why? Its saying undefined index

Comment: Yea, your foreach should look like this instead: `foreach($results as $result){echo $result['data'];}`

Comment: The two arrays have different values, so if I just do $results as $result, it will output "data" array on both $results, but if one array does not have 'data' then it will output an error for the array that does not contain data, this is why I'm only trying to get the first array to output data

Answer (score 0):

PHP's documentation has an example using [`curl_multi_exec`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-exec.php) . Basically, it creates two cURL handles, adds them to the `curl_multi_add_handle` interface, and then runs them in parallel.

Comment: If I'm able to output the results using curl_multi_getcontent, how do I request the values from the different arrays? I'm able to output 1 array, and another array, what is the best way to call the two arrays?