# Multiple curl json and json print

Tags: php, json, curl

I want to access multiples urls via curl and print the son output. I've seen this: [multiple cURL and output JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8470336/multiple-curl-and-output-json) but I`am not able make it work anyway...

my code:

```
<?php
$urls = Array(
 'URLtoJSON1',
 'URLtoJSON1'
);

for($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++) {
  $curl[$i] = curl_init($urls);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "YYY:XXX");
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $curl_post_data);
  $curl_response[$i] = curl_exec($curl);
  curl_close($curl);

  $data = json_decode($curl_response[$i]);
  $name[$i] = $data->fullDisplayName;
  $datum[$i] = $data->timestamp;
  $result[$i] = $data->result;

}

// here I`d love to be able echo output $name[URLtoJSON], etc...
?>
```

thank you for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of doing a `for` loop, you can make a `foreach` loop that iterates over your `$urls` array by doing `foreach ($urls as $key=>$url)`. `$key` will hold the index of the array (starting at 0) and `$url` will hold the URL.

Here is what the resulting code would look like:

```
$urls = Array(
    'URLtoJSON1',
    'URLtoJSON2'
);

foreach ($urls as $key=>$url) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "YYY:XXX");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $ch_post_data);
    $ch_response = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    $data = json_decode($ch_response);
    $name[$key] = $data->fullDisplayName;
    $datum[$key] = $data->timestamp;
    $result[$key] = $data->result;
}
```

Now if you want to access `$name` of the first URL, you would just do `$echo $name[0];`

You can also access `$datum` or `$result` in a similar way.

Comment: Thank you. Working like a charm :)