# Multiple cURL data been overwritten on PHP for each

Tags: php, curl

I need to call cURL multiple times to get different JSON responses so I followed the code in the answer of this question: 
[Multiple curl json and json print](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33973453/multiple-curl-json-and-json-print).

Now I realize that the variable that stores the return data is only holding the information from the last URL in the array (it's been overwritten). Here is my code:

```
$urls = Array(
 'https://example.com/projects/277199/roles.json',
 'https://example.com/projects/292291/roles.json'
 );


foreach ($urls as $key=>$url) {
 $ch = curl_init();
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "XXX:YYY");
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
 $ch_response = curl_exec($ch);
 curl_close($ch);
 $rolesData = json_decode($ch_response,true);
}

print_r($rolesData); //It's only printing the data from the last element in the urls array
```

How do I correctly store the data?

Comment: Please store the Data insight an array. Type **$rolesData[] = json_decode($ch_response,true);**

Comment: Yes! I was missing that, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just add `[]` or `[$key]` to `$rolesData`

```
    foreach ($urls as $key=>$url) {
     $ch = curl_init();
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "XXX:YYY");
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
     $ch_response = curl_exec($ch);
     curl_close($ch);
     $rolesData[] = json_decode($ch_response,true);
    }

print_r($rolesData);
```